Time Series Prediction with Hidden Variables
I have time series data sampled every 10 seconds. I want to predict a target variable  for 5 steps ahead using the input variable at the current time along with 10 past lags. My problem is that there is an unobserved hidden variable affecting the target variable . How can I infer this hidden unobserved variable and improve my predictions? I want to use Python for coding.
I used theano and arviz. But I'm not sure about the correct methodology.

This will be hard. The simplest approach would be to fit a model (or five models for the five steps, because if I understand correctly, you want to forecast all based on the current predictor value) on your known predictors, then fit a time series model to the residuals. You would hope this picks up on any structure. If there is structure in the hidden variable that turns into structure in the response, this might forecast it. This way, you could also include any patterns you might have ("seasonality"). We might be able to help more if you could give more details.

@StephanKolassa. My main target is to infer about the hidden variable and thereby improve model accuracy. I want to predict y t+5 using xt, xt-1,xt-2,..,xt-10. But this doesn't do the prediction well cos of that hidden variable which is dynamic That is why I want to infer the hidden variable and use it to improve prediction. I felt I should use dynamic Bayesian network for this task. What do you think? I'm not sure where to start.

I very much doubt that the workflow "inferring a hidden variable and feeding that into a predictive model" will yield more accurate predictions than "modeling and forecasting unexplained variation after accounting for all known predictors", because in the end, you don't know how accurate your reconstruction of the hidden variable was. As I wrote, if you could give us more details about your problem, we might be able to give better advice.
